# Android: How to fit GridView automatically to all screensizes?

Tags: android, gridview, android-relativelayout, screen-size, autosize

I've written a little app, it is my first android app. It's an infrared TV remote app, I developed using a Samsung Galaxy S4, where everything seems to be running fine.

This is how it looks on my Galaxsy S4: [Screenshot Samsung Galaxy S4](http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/galaxys46f5em9xn8i.jpg)

But since I've published to play store I got another screenshot from a Galaxy Note 2 user where it looks really messed up and does not fit to his screen: [Screenshot Samsung Galaxy Note 2](http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/notevm29g7j5ua.jpg)

This is my fragment's layout code, 
**fragment_page1.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<GridLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:rowCount="7"
    android:columnCount="5"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">






    // POWER

    <ImageButton
        android:onClick="pressPowerButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:id="@+id/power"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:src="@drawable/stand_by"
        android:layout_marginTop="1.5dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:onClick="pressButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="SLEEP"
        android:id="@+id/sleep"
        android:textColor="#2299bb"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="1.5dp"
        />

    // VOLUME

    <Button
        android:onClick="pressButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="Vol +"
        android:id="@+id/volUp"
        android:textColor="#2299bb"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        />

    <Button
        android:onClick="pressButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="Vol -"
        android:id="@+id/volDown"
        android:textColor="#2299bb"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0"
        />

    <Button
        android:onClick="pressButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="Mute"
        android:id="@+id/mute"
        android:textColor="#2299bb"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="0"
        />

    // PROGRAM
    <Button
        android:onClick="pressButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="Ch +"
        android:id="@+id/progUp"
        android:textColor="#2299bb"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="4"
        />

    <Button
        android:onClick="pressButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="Ch -"
        android:id="@+id/progDown"
        android:textColor="#2299bb"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="4"
        />

    <Button
        android:onClick="pressButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="CH LIST"
        android:id="@+id/chList"
        android:textColor="#2299bb"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="4"
        />

    <Button
        android:onClick="pressButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="Info"
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:textColor="#2299bb"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="3"
        />

    <Button
        android:onClick="pressButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="Guide"
        android:id="@+id/guide"
        android:textColor="#2299bb"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="3"
        />

    <Button
        android:onClick="pressButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="A"
        android:id="@+id/red"
        android:textColor="#cc2200"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="3"
        />

    // MENU

    <Button
        android:onClick="pressButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="Menu"
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:textColor="#777777"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-1.5dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:onClick="pressButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="Internet\n\@TV"
        android:id="@+id/internet"
        android:textColor="#777777"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-9.5dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="2"
        />

    <Button
        android:onClick="pressButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="Media\nPlay"
        android:id="@+id/media"
        android:textColor="#777777"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-9dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="2"
        />

    <Button
        android:onClick="pressButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="Tools"
        android:id="@+id/tools"
        android:textColor="#777777"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:onClick="pressButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="Source"
        android:id="@+id/source"
        android:textColor="#777777"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:onClick="pressButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="Content"
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:textColor="#777777"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-2.5dp"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="2"
        />

    // NAVIGATE

    <Button
        android:onClick="pressButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="\u25b2"
        android:id="@+id/up"
        android:textColor="#2299bb"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-4.5dp"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="2"
        />

    <Button
        android:onClick="pressButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="\u25bc"
        android:id="@+id/down"
        android:textColor="#2299bb"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:layout_column="2"
        />

    <Button
        android:onClick="pressButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="\u25c0"
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:textColor="#2299bb"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:onClick="pressButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="\u23ea"
        android:id="@+id/rewind"
        android:textColor="#777777"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-2.5dp"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="0"
        />


    <Button
        android:onClick="pressButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="\u23e9"
        android:id="@+id/forward"
        android:textColor="#777777"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-2.5dp"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="4"
        />

    <Button
        android:onClick="pressButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="\u25b7"
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:textColor="#777777"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:onClick="pressButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="II"
        android:id="@+id/pause"
        android:textColor="#777777"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="3"
        />

    <Button
        android:onClick="pressButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="\u25a0"
        android:id="@+id/stop"
        android:textColor="#777777"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:layout_column="3"
        />

    <Button
        android:onClick="pressButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="EXIT"
        android:id="@+id/exit"
        android:textColor="#777777"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:layout_column="4"
        />

    <Button
        android:onClick="pressButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="\u25cf"
        android:id="@+id/record"
        android:textColor="#777777"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:layout_column="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:onClick="pressButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="\u25b6"
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:textColor="#2299bb"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="3"
        />

    <Button
        android:onClick="pressButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="ENTER"
        android:id="@+id/ok"
        android:textColor="#118844"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="2"
        />

    <Button
        android:onClick="pressButton"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="RETURN\u21b6"
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:textColor="#cc2200"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-14dp"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="4"
        />

// PLACEHOLDER

    <Button
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/placeHolder1"
        android:textSize="8dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="2"
        />

    <Button
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/placeHolder2"
        android:textSize="8dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="3"
        />

    <Button
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:id="@+id/placeHolder3"
        android:textSize="8dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="4"
        />

    <Button
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/placeHolder4"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/placeHolder5"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
        />
</GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is from 
**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener
```

{

```
/* swipe view */
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private android.app.ActionBar actionBar;

// tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Basic", "Advanced", "Settings"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /* init swipe views */
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    for (String tabName : tabs)
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabName).setTabListener(this));

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
```

}

**So how can I improve this?** 
I've read articles and other post about it but nothing did work for me so far. I've tried combinations of fill_parent and match_parent, wrap_content for GridView, RelativeLayout tried other elements like GridLayout, LinearLayout and TableLayout, but I still don't get it :(

I know I use some bad workarounds like android:layout_marginTop="-2dp", without such workarounds I dont manage to display it correctly on my Galaxy S4. How to get rid of margins?

**So what I'm ultimatively looking for is an automatically scaling GridView with 5 columns and 7 rows that displays all buttons correctly also on larger screens**.

Do I need to do this programmatically or is there a solution using the layout file only?

I'd be so happy if somebody can help me out of trouble!

Comment: If somebody wants to download a copy, its already avaible on Play Store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.tzapp.smote

Comment: you just need to create multiple xml's and check if screen height/width is greater than, equal to and less than 
and in all three cases mention number of grid different

Comment: Also when you are going to inflate xml inside the .java class there you inflate xml of which case it meet the criteria.

Comment: Ok, still dont get it. Can you give an example please? Multiple xml's for what kind of elements?

Comment: **Does anybody have another solution please?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the height and width of grid item cell dynamically.
First you need to decide how many cell you want to show in grid row.
Set grid of cell 3 in xml.
Let's suppose you have Three cell for grid for each screen.
In your YourActivity.java file
Dynamically calculate width of screen.
Then decide the aspect ratio with how much width you want what height.

Algorithm :

```
expectedWidth = (screenWidth/number of cell) - ((padding or marjin between one cell to other)* (number of cell +1)  )
expectedHeight = expectedWidth*aspect ratio
```

you can adjust Aspect ratio for your proper height